# I can't find why memory isn't release using in SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

I'm making on some Winform application, I noticed my program's memory issue.

This is my winform custom control code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using DX = SharpDX;
using D2D = SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;
using DW = SharpDX.DirectWrite;

namespace WinFormTest
{
    public partial class BitmapSurface : Control
    {
        D2D.Factory d2dFactory;
        DW.Factory dwFactory;
        D2D.WindowRenderTarget wrt;
        D2D.BitmapRenderTarget brt;

        Rectangle clippingRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

        public BitmapSurface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeRenderer();
        }

        DX.Size2 clientSize2;
        DX.Size2F clientSize2f;

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);

            if (clientSize2 == null)
                clientSize2 = new DX.Size2();
            if (clientSize2f == null)
                clientSize2f = new DX.Size2F();

            clientSize2.Width = ClientSize.Width;
            clientSize2.Height = ClientSize.Height;

            clientSize2f.Width = ClientSize.Width;
            clientSize2f.Height = ClientSize.Height;


            if (wrt != null)
            {
                wrt.Resize(clientSize2);
            }
            if (brt != null)
            {
                brt.Dispose();
                brt = new D2D.BitmapRenderTarget(wrt, D2D.CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, clientSize2f, null, null);
                brt.AntialiasMode = D2D.AntialiasMode.Aliased;
            }

            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private D2D.SolidColorBrush GetBrush(float r, float g, float b, float a = 255)
        {
            var brush = new D2D.SolidColorBrush(
                wrt, new RawColor4(r / 255.0f, g / 255.0f, b / 255.0f, a / 255.0f));
            return brush;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);

            clippingRect = this.ClientRectangle;
            var rect = clippingRect;

            DrawBitmap();
        }

        public void InitializeRenderer()
        {
            int width = this.ClientSize.Width;
            int height = this.ClientSize.Height;

            D2D.HwndRenderTargetProperties hrtp = new D2D.HwndRenderTargetProperties();
            hrtp.Hwnd = this.Handle;
            hrtp.PixelSize = new DX.Size2(width, height);

            // D2DFactory
            if (d2dFactory == null)
                d2dFactory = new D2D.Factory();

            // DirectWrite
            if (dwFactory == null)
                dwFactory = new DW.Factory();

            wrt = new D2D.WindowRenderTarget(d2dFactory, new D2D.RenderTargetProperties(), hrtp);
            wrt.AntialiasMode = D2D.AntialiasMode.Aliased;

            brt = new D2D.BitmapRenderTarget(wrt, D2D.CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, new DX.Size2F(width, height), null, null);
            brt.AntialiasMode = D2D.AntialiasMode.Aliased;
        }

        public void DrawBitmap()
        {
            brt.BeginDraw();
            brt.Clear(new RawColor4(0, 0, 0, 1));

            // Draw Something
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                brt.DrawLine(
                    new RawVector2(0, i),
                    new RawVector2(90, 90 + i),
                    GetBrush(255, 255, 255));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                brt.FillRectangle(
                    new RawRectangleF(90, 0 + i, 150, 10 + i),
                    GetBrush(255 - i, 255 - i, 255 - i));
            }

            brt.EndDraw();

            wrt.BeginDraw();
            wrt.DrawBitmap(brt.Bitmap, 1, D2D.BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor);
            wrt.EndDraw();
        }
    }
}
```

My program's mainform can have many childs, Child draw somethings with SharpDX.

Memory usage is increase When I open child forms, but after closing child form and GC.Collect memory usage is NOT decrease.

Is this bad usage for SharpDX?

Comment: Sharpdx requires you to manage the objects that you create from it's library.  As such, for your child windows, any new objects you create as part of the child window should be directly released/disposed of as part of the lift cycle.  Garbage collector will not free unmanaged objects, these objects themselves are COM objects and have a reference count that is only decremented when you execute the dispose.

Comment: Thanks. I find some objects that remained references.